# Looking to apply a string replace for all columns of a Polars DataFrame without specifying each column

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to apply a string replace to a Polars DataFrame, similar to how you would apply it to a Pandas DataFrame.

I would like the equivalent to the following:

`df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("A", "B")`

I understand with Polars you can use the following:

```
`
df=df.with_columns(
    pl.col("col1").str.replace("A", "B"),
    pl.col("col2").str.replace("A", "B"))`
```

Is there a way to apply it to all columns? I have a very large DataFrame (100+ columns) and would prefer to not have to specify all columns.

I've tried using:

```
df = df.select([
    pl.all().map(lambda x: x.replace("A", "B"), df)
])
```

and I get an error: `ValueError: Cannot infer dtype from 'shape: (150000, 150)`

Is there something that I may be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all columns of a certain type, or multiple columns. See [Selectors](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) for more.

```py
df=df.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.replace("A", "B"))
```

`pl.all().str` ... is fine too if the df is fully string columns.

Comment: Just tried this and it works great, thank you!

Comment: You can also write it as: 

`import polars.selectors as cs
df.with_columns(cs.string().str.replace("A", "B"))
`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your initial solution:

```
df = df.select([
    pl.all().map(lambda x: x.replace("A", "B"), df)
])
```

Try:

```
df = df.with_columns([
    pl.all().str.replace("A", "B")
])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).